# Using .NET 3.5 features on .NET 2.0.... and it's working?

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, .net-2.0

My .NET app runs as a plugin to a C++ MFC desktop app which provides a .NET SDK. The main app is in charge of loading .NET before it loads any plugins. I'm compiling my project against .NET 3.5, and the following test code works just fine:

```
    MainApp.WriteLine("MyPlugin running on .NET {0}.{1}", _
                       System.Environment.Version.Major, _
                       System.Environment.Version.Minor)

    Dim data As Int32() = New Int32() {1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 12, 12, 12, 12}
    For Each distinctValue As Int32 In data.Distinct()
      MainApp.Write(distinctValue.ToString() & ", ")
    Next
```

This is Linq code which *should* only run on .NET 3.5 right? However when it prints the version message it claims that "MyPlugin running on .NET 2.0"

Why/How is this working and can I rely on it to always work, provided .NET 3.5 has been installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a guess, it is reporting the core version of .NET, which is 2.0. This was not updated unti lversion 4.0, because the core code is the same.

Comment: Ahhhh, so how do I test for the /actual/ version?

Comment: Which *actual* version? The *actual* version of the .NET runtime is 2.0. Later versions of .NET (3.0 and 3.5, including service packs) weren't new versions of the runtime environment, just new libraries and some compiler tricks. If you care, try to use a type defined in a .NET 3.5 only library, and an exception will throw if it's not available.

Comment: I suppose the *actual* version is the version that was downloaded and installed by the user. 2.0, 3.0, 3.5 or 4.0 at present. That's the versions my customers think in because that's the versions they see on the microsoft webpages. So if someone *only* has 2.0 installed, I need the message to read "2.0", if someone *only* has 3.5 installed I need the message to read "3.5". If someone has both installed I want to know which of the two is currently actually loaded. I'll use your solution if needed, but it hard to believe this information cannot be got at without throwing exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Some features in .net 3.5 are only syntactic sugar, and the compiler compiles them to MSIL that can be executed by the 2.0 runtime.
So you only need VS 2008 and .net 3.5 on your development machine, but the machines where the compiled app will run on need only the 2.0 runtime.

See this question here at SO:
[What features of .NET 3.5 can be used in a .NET 2.0 application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406065/what-features-of-net-3-5-can-be-used-in-a-net-2-0-application)