# Confused about using .Net 3.5+ features in a 2.0 site

Tags: .net

In VS 2010 I set my target framework to 2.0. In the code it is letting me use the var keyword as well as implicit properties (public int Foo { get; set; }).

Not only does this build but when I upload the dll to my ASP.Net 2.0 site, the site runs the code fine.

What gives?

Comment: This is probably an exact duplicate of [What features of .NET 3.5 can be used in a .NET 2.0 application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406065/what-features-of-net-3-5-can-be-used-in-a-net-2-0-application) and/or [C# 3.0 compatibility on .Net 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404507/c-3-0-compatibility-on-net-2-0), both of which have some excellent answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting confused between C# and .NET.

These are C# 3.0 features. They have nothing to do with the version of .NET you're using.

Comment: So any future versions of C# can run on any previous version of .NET? Doesn't the compiler have to be upgrade when new features come out?

Comment: Most compiler features do not require support from the framework or the CLR. Generics, for instance, required CLR support. Automatic properties require no support - the compiler simply invents a backing field, so they look just like "normal" properties.

Answer (score 0):

var and implicit properties ("auto-implemented properties") are aspects of *C# 3.0*, not .NET. C# 3.0 and 2.0 can both compile to .NET 2.0, with a few exceptions - in other words, the features you mention (and some others) are purely syntactic sugar that compile down to the same IL constructs that have been available since .NET 2.0.

There is a [section](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter1/Versions.aspx) of Jon Skeet's "C# In Depth" online that explains this very well. Note that not *all* features of C# 3.0 are available in .NET 2.0.